# Send a Message to Members in Drupal-6?

Tags: php, drupal-6, content-management-system, message

How can I have my own mailing list members? To send an email to all of them.
How is this done?

Of course, I mean, not the newsletter.

Comment: There's a [drupal.SE] site, did you search there?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Simple News](http://drupal.org/project/simplenews) module for newsletters.

Comment: Excuse me. I mean, is not news.

Comment: Could you please clarify, do you need to send emails to mailing list, created from your site's users? or you need private messages?
if you're talking about emails, Simple news mentioned above suits you perfectly, in additional it has hell bunch of extensions modules, check them at Simple news page.

Comment: @nima, I'm not sure what you're asking in the comment here.